# Convert milliseconds into datetime in perl

Tags: perl

I have a file with miliseconds value such as "1366535578" which I need to convert into datetime. In python I can do as below

```
import datetime
print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1366535578)
```

How can it be achieved in perl so that it displays in format "20130421181258"

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It isn't milliseconds. That is **seconds** since epoch.

Comment: If any of the answers below have helped you, then accept them or tell us what is not working .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Milliseconds actually denote duration and not time .

You can use this :

```
use POSIX qw( strftime );
my $formatted = strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", localtime($ts/1000));
```

The string `strftime` is your milliseconds string .

This gives you `YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format, if you want you can remove the hiphens to get your format or arrange it to arrive at yours.

**NOTE :** Removed the hiphens and colons in the format string .

Comment: ..or you could remove the hyphens and colons in the format string itself.

Comment: @DarkCthulhu : I was in a little hurry, so didn't do that. I am gonna edit as per the OP's format string .

Answer (score 2):

The core [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece) module will do this for you. It overrides the built-in `localtime` function so that it has an `strftime` method:

```
use Time::Piece;

print localtime(1366535578)->strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S');
```

**output**

```
20130421101258
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my @date = localtime(time);
$date[5] += 1900;
$date[4] += 1;
$date[2] = '0'.$date[2] if ($date[2] < 10);
$date[1] = '0'.$date[1] if ($date[1] < 10);
$date[4] = '0'.$date[4] if ($date[4] < 10);
$date[3] = '0'.$date[3] if ($date[3] < 10);
print join(@date,'');
```

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html